# Передача ссылки на список в функцию

Tags: c++

Собственно проблема не в самой передаче а в дальнейшей работе со списком:

```
template < typename T > void minmaxList( const list< T > &listRef ) {
    int min=0,max=0,i=0;
    list<int>::iterator it;
    for( it=listRef.begin(); it != listRef.end(); ++it ) {
       if (*it==1){ 
          min=*it;
          max=*it;
       }
       if (*it<=min) min=*it;
       if (*it>=max) max=*it;
    }
    cout<<"\tMIN: "<<min<<"\tMAX"<<max<<endl;
}
```

Соответственно заголовок функции

```
template < typename T > void minmaxList( const std::list< T > &listRef );
```

список объявляем list<int> L;
Возникает ошибка при компиляции:

```
[Error] no match for 'operator=' in 'it = (& listRef)->std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>, std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_List_const_iterator<int>]()'
```

на строке где я получаю итератор:
    list<int>::iterator it;

Собственно что не так?

Полный код программы http://govnokod.com/6728 ошибка на строке 38

Сделал вот так: http://govnokod.com/6734

Comment: У вас список объявлен как `list<T>`, а итератор - как `list<int>::iterator`. Правильно, соответственно, объявлять итератор как `list<T>::iterator`. Можно это даже затайпдефить.

Comment: Если поставить вместо INT, T то возникает воз ошибок, на этой и следующей строке. Но если из функции перенести в тело main() то все ок, а как отдельная функция - работать не хочет.

Comment: Если оставить <int> при объявлении итератора, то можно не делать функцию шаблонной. Она всё равно не будет работать ни с чём, кроме списка int'ов.

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то `*it==1` не имеет смысла ни для чего, кроме типов, приводящихся к `int'у,` а `<` имеет смысл заменить на `std::less`. Ну и да, `T` должен быть `CopyConstructible`.

Comment: я считаю, что нужно 38-ю строчку переписать как 

    std::list<int>::iterator it;

Comment: И используйте const_iterator НАКОНЕЦ!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы передаёте список как конст ссылку на список, по идее и итератор должен быть константным.

```
std::list<T>::const_iterator it;
```

Comment: [Error] need 'typename' before 'std::list<T>::const_iterator' because 'std::list<T>' is a dependent scope.
    И сразу следующая ошибка говорит что ожидает ; перед it

Comment: У меня ошибок в vs 12 не наблюдается.

Поставьте typename перед 

typename list<int>::iterator it;

Может быть компилятор считает list<int>::iterator статическим членом и нужно явно указать что имеется ввиду тип.

Comment: Тогда продолжаем разговор
[Error] no match for 'operator=' in 'it = (& listRef)->std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>, std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_List_const_iterator<int>]()'

Comment: Вы можете выложить весь код того что компилируете?
Не понятно что изменили и где.

Comment: http://govnokod.com/6734 

сейчас вот так, все работает, но если сверху оставлю только заголовки функций а остальное вниз перемещу - работать не будет.

Comment: а здесь вам нужно уже про шаблоны почитать. шаблонный класс и функция должны быть видны полностью до использования, как то так ))

Comment: Вообще то нет. template указывать надо, а определять саму функцию не обязательно.

Comment: почему нельзя шаблоны компилировать раздельно? объявление в хеадере а реализация в с файле? нужно вразу что бы было реализация в хеадере. это шаблоны и они такие ))

Comment: Шаблоны МОЖНО компилировать раздельно, но лучше не надо.... Насколько я помню, это умеет делать компилятор Comeau C/C++, а еще хотели это в стандарт включить.

Comment: ну и вот, зачем делать так как может сделать какой то ноу нейм компилятор и то что стандартом не поддерживается.

Comment: Комо - ни разу не нонейм, а вообще-то наиболее корректный компилятор. Но это тема для отдельного разговора.

Comment: В студии это тоже возможно. 
А смысл того что этого нет в стандарте? 
Нельзя скомпилировать модуль не зная какой тип будет у шаблона?

То есть те компиляторы, которые могут выполнять подобную компиляцию, вынуждены пере компилировать те модули у которых тип шаблона любого шаблонного объекта изменился со времени последней компиляции, тем самым сводя повышение скорости компиляции решения, за счёт принципов раздельной компиляции, на нет?